# SAS: attempting to build a loop for uploading multiple files

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm attempting to build a loop in SAS to upload several files, and am running into a few issues to work through.  Current code:

```
%Macro Weatherupload(File=, output=);
proc import datafile = &File;
out = &output;
dbms=dlm replace;
delimiter= ",";
getnames=yes;
guessingrows = 1000;
run;
%Mend Weatherupload;

%Macro WeatherPrepare(input=, output=);
data &output (keep=Wban_Number _YearMonthDay DewPoint Temp _Avg_Dew_Pt _Avg_Temp year month day);
set &input;
DewPoint = Input(compress(_Avg_Dew_Pt,"*"), 3.);
Temp = Input(compress(_Avg_Temp,"*"), 3.);
year = (_yearmonthday - mod(_yearmonthday, 10000))/10000;
month = ((_yearmonthday - mod(_yearmonthday, 100)) - (_yearmonthday - mod(_yearmonthday,10000)))/100;
day = mod(_yearmonthday, 100);
drop _Avg_Dew_Pt _Avg_Temp _YearMonthDay;
run;
%Mend WeatherPrepare;

data temperatures;
do i = 1999 to 2015;
do j = 1 to 12;
name = 'C:\Users\DILLON.SAXE\Documents\'||i||j||'.tar'||'   \'||i||j||'daily.txt';
output = i||j||'weather';
final = i||j||'final';
%Weatherupload(File=name, output=output)
%WeatherPrepare(input=output, output=final)
end;
end;
run;
```

The goal is to run through several files, in several folders, listed in month + day + rest of title, and (at the moment) upload two variables of data from them.  Later I will want to add in merging the files, and doing some more data work, but for the moment it's the macro issues and uploading that are holding it up.

Is there a way to either use proc upload in a loop, or use another data step in the loop?

I get the error "more positional variables than (something)"  (I forget exact error, but it lists positional variables).  I've tried adding and removing commas in the macros, but have not been able to get rid of this error.  Any ideas?

Comment: There is no proc upload that I'm familiar with.

Comment: @Reeza [PROC UPLOAD](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/connref/61908/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002558373.htm) is part of SAS/Connect.  It's not widely used anymore.

Comment: Upload where? SAS server, ftp, http?

Comment: Your WeatherPrepare macro seems to make assumptions about the names of the fields in the tables imported from CSV files.  If you know the structure of the CSV file then you should read them using a data step instead of PROC IMPORT.  This will avoid many of the troubles caused by PROC IMPORT having to guess what your variables are.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can call macro's like you have in your data step. I think you're intending to use `Call Execute`.

```
data temperatures;
do i = 1999 to 2015;
do j = 1 to 12;
name = 'C:\Users\DILLON.SAXE\Documents\'||i||j||'.tar'||'   \'||i||j||'daily.txt';
output = i||j||'weather';
final = i||j||'final';
call execute('%Weatherupload(File='||name||', output='||output||')');
call execute('%WeatherPrepare(input='||output||', output='||final||')');
end;
end;
run;
```

Alternatively, assuming you're trying to read all files in a folder, I think you should be creating a list of file names in a data set, use a data step with the filename option to input all files at once instead. Here's a brief method on how to do it if all where in a single folder: https://communities.sas.com/docs/DOC-10426

Answer (score 0):

Here is a page that has code to get a list of files into a data set

http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Making_Lists

since your macros have neither conditionals (%if) nor loops (%do)
then I suggest you use them as parameterized %incudes

Here is a tool to read the list-of-files data set and call a program

http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Call_Execute_Parameterized_Include

note: in proc import always set guessingrows to the max value;
in v9.3 that is 2147483647;

Comment: Ron - on SO, we don't allow answers that are primarily only links to elsewhere; the answer must contain all information itself to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted out, based on the first answer.  Eventual code:

```
%Macro Weatherupload(File=, output=);
proc import datafile = "&File"
out = &output
dbms=dlm replace;
delimiter= ",";
getnames=yes;
guessingrows = 1000;
run;
%Mend Weatherupload;

%Macro WeatherPrepare(input=, output=);
data &output;
set &input;
DewPoint = Input(compress(_Avg_Dew_Pt,"*"), 3.);
Temp = Input(compress(_Avg_Temp,"*"), 3.);
year = (_yearmonthday - mod(_yearmonthday, 10000))/10000;
month = ((_yearmonthday - mod(_yearmonthday, 100)) - (_yearmonthday - mod(_yearmonthday,10000)))/100;
day = mod(_yearmonthday, 100);
keep Wban_Number DewPoint Temp year month day;
run;
%Mend WeatherPrepare; 

%Macro WeatherPrepare2(input=, output=);
data &output;
set &input;
DewPoint = Input(DewPoint, 3.);
Temp = Input(compress(_Avg_Temp,"*"), 3.);
year = (_yearmonthday - mod(_yearmonthday, 10000))/10000;
month = ((_yearmonthday - mod(_yearmonthday, 100)) - (_yearmonthday - mod(_yearmonthday,10000)))/100;
day = mod(_yearmonthday, 100);
Wban_Number = Wban;
keep Wban_Number DewPoint Temp year month day;
run;
%Mend WeatherPrepare; 

%Macro Append(merge=);
data temperatures;
set temperatures &merge;
%Mend Append;

data temperatures;
do i = 1999 to 2015;
do j = 1 to 12;
jzero = put(j, z2.);
name = compress('C:\Users\DILLON.SAXE\Documents\'||i||jzero||'.tar'||'\'||i||jzero||'daily.txt');
name2 = compress('C:\Users\DILLON.SAXE\Documents\'||'QCLCD'||i||jzero||'\'||i||jzero||'daily.txt');
output = compress('weather'||i||j);
final = compress('final'||i||j);
if 1000*i+j < 200708 then
do;
call execute('%Weatherupload(File='||name||', output='||output||')');
call execute('%WeatherPrepare(input='||output||', output='||final||')');
end;
else
do;
call execute('%Weatherupload(File='||name2||', output='||output||')');
call execute('%WeatherPrepare2(input='||output||', output='||final||')');
end;
call execute('%Append(merge='||final||')');
end;
end;
drop i j jzero name name2 output final;
run;
```